# Run a perl script at startup in Ubuntu

Tags: perl, ubuntu, startupscript

I have a perl script that I need to run once at startup with an argument **under my user account**.

So when I boot the system up it needs to execute a command like this,

```
./path/to/script.pl start
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Offtopic - try http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 7):

You could use a line in your crontab (crontab -e)

To run a command at startup:

edit /etc/crontab
Add the following line:

@reboot root perl ./path/to/script.pl start

^^^ Runs as root. Change "root" to "BlackCow" to run as BlackCow

Or, you could use upstart (add a .conf file to /etc/init/). Here's a copy and paste from my notes:

Use upstart to run a daemon at reboot/start

e.g. /etc/init/prestocab.conf:

```
#!upstart
description "node.js server"
author      "BlackCow"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on shutdown

script
    export HOME="/root"

    exec sudo -u root /usr/local/bin/node /home/prestocab/prestocab.com/www/socket.io/server.js 2>&1 >> /var/log/prestocab.log
end script
```

To use:

```
start prestocab
stop prestocab
restart prestocab
```

#
You might want to use some sort of process monitor to restart the daemon if it crashes

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what `init` you are using, if your version of Ubuntu is using [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html)

you have to configure the appropriate Upstart start scripts, if not
the `rc` scripts based on your `runlevel`. Check `update-rc.d`.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu, the simplest way is to add this line to your `/etc/rc.local` file (before the `exit 0` line, substituting `username` with your own user name):

```
su -c "./path/to/script.pl start" username &
```